# Apache - Nginx Rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

I am stuck with a Apache "Rewrite" to Nginx conversion.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.app17web\.dev1\.whispir\.net             [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/s/                                                [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jsp/                                    [NC]
RewriteRule .* /jsp/portal/404/austpost/index.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new2\.app17web\.dev1\.whispir\.net            [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/s/                                                [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jsp/                                    [NC]
RewriteRule .* /jsp/portal/404/austpost/index.html

I have in my Nginx config :
    location / {

    if ($http_host ~ "^new.app17web.dev1.whispir.net"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }

    if ($uri !~ "^/s/"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }

    if ($uri !~ "^/jsp/"){
    set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
    }

    if ($rule_0 = "321"){
    rewrite /.* /jsp/portal/404/austpost/index.html;
    }

    if ($http_host ~ "^new2.app17web.dev1.whispir.net"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }

    if ($uri !~ "^/s/"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }

    if ($uri !~ "^/jsp/"){
    set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
    }

    if ($rule_0 = "321"){
    rewrite /.* /jsp/portal/404/austpost/index.html;
    }

      try_files $uri @mainWorker;
    }
```

And my @mainWorker is :

```
    location @mainWorker {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
        proxy_pass  http://mainWorker;

    }
```

I also have a proxy.conf

```
underscores_in_headers  on;
proxy_intercept_errors  on;
proxy_redirect         off;
client_max_body_size    10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
```

What i get is :

Forbidden
 Your access privileges to not allow you to access this content.
 The information that you have requested is no longer available or has expired. 
 Please Go Back to the page you arrived from, or return to the Whispir Login Page.
If I do not have the rewrites in place, it all works fine, but when I add them in, I get the forbidden.

Is there anyone who can point out my config error please.

Thanks.
     G

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.
The if statements in the location block point upstream, checking /jsp/portal/404/austpost/index.html; , this is not upstream it is local to the Nginx server.

So took the if statements out of the location / block and all is ok.

Made too many assumptions that it was going upstream to my Jboss servers.

Thanks for looking though.

ATB.

G